# jQuery wrap() method

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to wrap all three `<span>` in one `<div>` ?

```
<span class='wrap'>Span 1</span>

<span class='wrap'>Span 2</span>

<span class='wrap'>Span 3</span>
```

Here is a wrapper `<div id="parentWrapper"></div>`

Upon my running code below each `span` has an individual `<div>` and alerts three times its context

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span.wrap').wrap('<div id="parentWrapper">');
    $('div#parentWrapper').each(function(){
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `wrapAll()` method

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements.

```
 $('span.wrap').wrapAll('<div id="parentWrapper">');
```

Reference [wrapAll() docs](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)